# Prove all real polynomials of degree $n(n \geq 1)$ can be factorized to the product of k linear factors and l quadratic factors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Prove all real polynomials of degree $n(n \geq 1)$ can be factorized to the product of k linear factors and l quadratic factors following holds

1. $k$ and $l$ are integers ($k \geq 1, l \geq 0$)
2. All linear factors and quadratic factors are real polynomial
3. Every quadratic factor has no real root($b^2-4ac < 0$ at $ax^2+bx+c)$

How can I prove this? It seems that I can use mathematical induction but I have no idea about details.

Comment: Did you quote the problem correctly? – The second factor has no zeros, so this would imply that every real-coefficient polynomial has at most one real root.

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: It still looks wrong to me. What would that factorization be for $P(x) = x(x-1)(x-2)$?

Comment: What you probably mean is: Every polynomial with real coefficients can be factored into factors all of which have the form $(px+q)^k$ or $(ax^2+bx+c)^l$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/304466/42969.

Comment: I have edited it. And math.stackexchange.com/q/304466/42969 is that exactly I want.