# Can every two-variant polynomial can be factored up to quadratic factors?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, polynomials

I know for a univariant polynomial, the proposition is affirmed. [Can every real polynomial be factored up to quadratic factors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304466/can-every-real-polynomial-be-factored-up-to-quadratic-factors)
But how about two-variant polynomial? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative.

A bivariate quadratic polynomial corresponds to a conic. A factorization as the product of bivariate quadratic polynomials would correspond to a set of conics (plus a straight line for odd degrees), which is in general not the case.

E.g. $$x^4+y^4=1$$ describes a so-called superellipse, which is not the union of two conics.

[image]